# Did the INR/USD exchange rate experience a spike around Oct-Nov 2023?

Tags: economics, india, google, currency

If we look at Google search's graph of INR/USD exchange rate, there is this big spike somewhere around October or November 2023.

Did this happen for real, or does Google have buggy data?

[image: graph of the exchange rate between the Indian rupee and the American dollar that shows a dramatic spike sometime between Oct/Nov 2023.]

Comment: USDCAD data shows a similar spike in the opposite direction for mid-November of 2022, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to say that it's a bug in Google's data.

[Hovering over your graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8iHU.png) explains that $1 in USD was (purportedly) ₹85.20 on Nov 1, 2023. Searching Google for `November 1 2023 USD to Rupee "85.20"` offers no relevant or reliable results, although there was a Reddit thread asking about this. It does turn out to be the case that 1/11/23 was (at the time) the rupee's nadir, but the actual value was never ₹85.20.

To compare, here is the graph on *[Pound Sterling Live](https://www.poundsterlinglive.com/history/USD-INR-2023)*, which shows that it was somewhere closer to ₹83.2717:

> [image]

---

Here are some other sources:

**1.**  *[The Economic Times](https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/markets/forex/rupee-closes-slightly-higher-dollar-demand-from-importers-caps-gain/articleshow/104916152.cms)* reported on Thursday, Nov. 2 2023:

> The local unit fell to its **lifetime low of 83.2950 on Wednesday** but recovered to open at 83.2250 on Thursday as U.S. Treasury yields fell and the dollar softened after the Federal Reserve left rates unchanged.

**2.** [*The Hindu*](https://www.thehindu.com/business/rupee-updates-on-november-1-2023/article67483419.ece), at 10:05 a.m. IST on Nov. 1 2023:

> The rupee depreciated 3 paise to 83.27 against the US dollar in the morning session on Wednesday, November 1, 2023 tracking a strong American currency overseas and muted trend in domestic equities.

**3.** [*Exchange-rates.org*](https://www.exchange-rates.org/exchange-rate-history/usd-inr-2023-11-01), which says that it was ₹83.26670.